# Error using codenameone bluetooth support

Tags: codenameone

I am building an app that uses bluetooth support. After adding the libs and refreshing as directed here https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone, Below is the error log

Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support

Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\build\tmp
C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:14: error: package com.codename1.bluetoothle does not exist
import com.codename1.bluetoothle.Bluetooth;

C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:359: error: cannot find symbol
    private Bluetooth bt;
  symbol:   class Bluetooth
  location: class StateMachine

C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:222: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
                    findCbAccounts().setModel(new DefaultListModel(new String[]{"No accounts"}));
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:229: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
                    findCbAccounts().setModel(new DefaultListModel(new String[]{"No accounts"}));
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:306: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
        cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(new String[]{"No accounts"}));
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:491: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
        cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(new String[]{"Savings", "Loan"}));
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java:497: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
        cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(new String[]{"         "}));
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

Note: C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\src\userclasses\StateMachine.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
5 warnings

C:\Users\RuffCode\Documents\mpayment\build.xml:56: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Any help and reason as to why it happened would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For me, this is an import error. You are definitely sure that you didnt put that libs accidently under /target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cn1lib's are just zip files so make sure you downloaded the right file by verifying that it's a valid zip file.

You can use the new [extension install tool](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/automatically-install-update-distribute-cn1libs-extensions.html) to install the library more easily.

Comment: I tried it. Now i get the error package com.codename1.bluetoothle does not exist
import com.codename1.bluetoothle.Bluetooth;

Comment: Check under the lib/impl directory that class file should exist in the hierarchy there. Is it there?

Comment: Is the error you are getting and actual compile error or is it just an IDE highlight? The latter are flaky. Which IDE are you using? Did you change the classpath in any way?

Comment: It says Build Failed anytime i try to build and that's the error I get. I am using netbeans 8.1 and I haven't changed the classpath. It's only the build.xml i edited to include my username and password

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the error log and post a comment when you do it so I'll see the question changed?

Comment: I need the full log as it might contain clues to what went wrong. If the class is in place then it should compile

Comment: Are you using an old project? Go to the codename one settings and click OK, does it offer to update `build.xml` ? If so accept that and try again.

Comment: I don't get you. Click OK on what exactly?

Comment: In the new Codename One settings it's a "save icon" on the top right. In the older IDE dialogs it's the OK button on the bottom right .

Comment: I still don't get you. Right clicking on the project and clicking codenameone settings i see nothing but preferences and the save icon next to the close. Clicking on the save button exits the dialog and nothing happens.Also after cloning the BTDemo it works fine but including the libs is what gives the error I'm talking about

Comment: That means the build.xml isn't out of date, if it was (which was my assumption) you would have gotten a prompt. I just tried this myself. New project, Codename One Settings, Extensions, search for JSON and install, search for Bluetooth and install. Add import `import com.codename1.bluetoothle.Bluetooth;` then create a Bluetooth object in the init(Object) method... All compiled and ran then sent the build... No problem. I'm totally stumped at where this process could have failed?

Comment: Guess I will create a new project then and download the libs at the beginning since that works. Thanks...